# foreach only pass last elemet to component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a component inside a livewire component. but foreach only pass the last element to component. whenever I click the card, modal shows the same course info

cards inside foreach (livewire component)

```php
@foreach($this->courses as $course)
    <a @click='showModal = true' id="{{$course->id}}">
        <div class="px-8 py-6">
            <h2 class="text-base font-bold flex items-center mt-3">
                    {{ $course->title }}
            </h2>
            <div class="">
                <div class="flex items-center">
                    {{ $course->desc }}
                </div>
            </div>                           
        </div>                          
    </a>               
    <x-sections.course-modal :course="$course"/>      
@endforeach
```

modal (component)

```php
<div id="{{$course->id}}" class="" x-cloak x-show="showModal">            
    <div class="px-14 pb-6">
        <h2 class="">
                {{ $course->title }}
        </h2>                       
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `course id` pass the `loop index` using `$loop->index`. I guess this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have 2 elements with the same ID. This is never a good practice. Convert the modal ID to e.g. `modal-{{$course->id}}`.

Second, there is no differentiating factor for your `showModal`. Therefore, all modals will show, since they are in the same scope. You're not showing us how you are creating the `showModal` data, however I assume you have an `x-data="{'showModal': false}"` somewhere up in the hierarchy. Instead, wrap the `x-data` in each loop to ensure the data is scoped to each individual modal:

```html
@foreach($this->courses as $course)
    <div x-data="{'showModal': false}">
        <a @click='showModal = true' id="{{$course->id}}">
            {{-- // --}}
        </a>
        <x-sections.course-modal :course="$course"/>
    </div>
@endforeach
```